# vitest Svelte App with Typescript : ParseError ... Unexpected token ` : `

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, svelte, vitest

I am trying to setup some unit-tests with `vitest` on a `Svelte` Application (with `Typescript` support), and I get the following error:

```yaml
ParseError: D:/(...)/src/Overlay.svelte:23:17 Unexpected token
```

In this file, that correspond to:

```html
<!-- Overlay.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">   // line 1
    //  (...)
    let startDate:string = tomorrows_date();  // line 23
//               ^--23:17
```

I have tried to reproduce the structure from the [official Vitest example on GitHub](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/examples/svelte).

I looked a bit everywhere and tried to use `vitest-svelte-kit` or adding a `svelte.config.js` (Which doesn't work because of the `import` statement "outside a module")

Find below my config.

In my `package.json` I added all of this:

```json
// package.json
   (...)
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear -c",
    "validate": "svelte-check",
    "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:ui": "vitest --ui",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.1.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.0.0",
     (...)
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^1.0.0-next.45",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.1.3",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^2.0.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "latest",
    "jsdom": "latest",
    "rollup": "^2.67.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.5",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "svelte": "^3.49.0",
    "svelte-check": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "vitest": "^0.18.1",
    "vitest-svelte-kit": "^0.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.2",
    "svelte-material-ui": "^6.0.0-beta.16"
  },
  "stackblitz": {
    "startCommand": "npm run test:ui"
  }
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"]
}
```

```js
// vitest.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        svelte({ hot: !process.env.VITEST }),
    ],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
    },
})
```

I don't have a `svelte.config.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TS requires [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess), the test config probably does not load it implicitly. You can [pass it to the plugin](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/config.md#preprocess) or configure it via the `svelte.config.js`:

```js
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ ... })
};
```

Comment: When I try to add this in `svelte.config.js`, I have an error that `import cannot be used outside of a module` 

Comment: And if I try to set `type: "module"` inside the `package.json` I get 10 more errors popping up.

Comment: You can probably reformulate it to CommonJS using `const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');` and change the export to `module.exports = defineConfig(...)`.

Comment: Though the `vitest.config.js` you posted in the question was in ES format, so that should have caused errors even before.

Comment: That is the thing : the  `vitest.config.js` is working ! 

Comment: Well, if Rollup does not like ES but Vitest does, you'll have to use the appropriate formats for each one.

Comment: So that was almost it, I had to edit the svelte config like this : 
`const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');`
`module.exports = {   preprocess: sveltePreprocess({  })   };` 
[Details here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/docs/usage.md#with-svelte-config)
Could you update your answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: My code was intended directly for the test config, but you can of course use the `svelte.config.js` as well. Adjusted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following configuration in your vitest config file :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      hot: !process.env.VITEST,
      preprocess: [sveltePreprocess({ typescript: true })] // <-- this line allow vitest to parse svelte component using typescript
    })
  ],
  test: {
    include: ['imports/**/*.vitest.{js,ts}'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
})
```

Comment: it would be better to write the code instead.

Comment: i updated it so